# How to select values from XML type column in oracle 12g

Tags: xml, oracle12.1

Below is my xml column with name xml_col. I want to select c11

```
<row id="GHKY5678" xml:space="preserve">
    <c1>ITVC</c1>
    <c2>USD1271500010001</c2>
    <c4>1</c4>
    <c5>USD</c5>
    <c6>275000.00</c6>
    <c7>20211001</c7>
    <c9>008107318011021</c9>
    <c10>Cr.Advice0085962</c10>
    <c11>101100002684</c11>
    <c12>1</c12>
    <c13>USD</c13>
    <c15>20211001</c15>
    <c18>20211001</c18>
</row>
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS and its version.
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

A CTE simulates your real table.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X2QH5lgi)

**SQL**

```
with tbl as
(
    select
        XMLType(
        '<row id="GHKY5678" xml:space="preserve">
            <c1>ITVC</c1>
            <c2>USD1271500010001</c2>
            <c4>1</c4>
            <c5>USD</c5>
            <c6>275000.00</c6>
            <c7>20211001</c7>
            <c9>008107318011021</c9>
            <c10>Cr.Advice0085962</c10>
            <c11>101100002684</c11>
            <c12>1</c12>
            <c13>USD</c13>
            <c15>20211001</c15>
            <c18>20211001</c18>
        </row>'
        ) xml_col
    from dual
)
select c11
from   tbl,
       xmltable('/row' 
           PASSING tbl.xml_col 
           COLUMNS c11 VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'c11');
```

**Output**

| C11 |
| --- |
| 101100002684 |

Comment: I fail in getting below query running properly on multiple elements in a XML View on a Oracle Database 12.

Comment: select * from xml_analysis tbl,
           xmltable('/row' 
           PASSING tbl.soft_attributes 
           COLUMNS c11 VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'c11');

Comment: ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence

Comment: Please see my comments under your original question.